# How to link the CS50 C library in GCC on Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, cs50

I'm new to С programming and have been trying to compile my code using [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW)/GCC, but I try to include the [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50) (*cs50.c*, *cs50.h*) library, and the compiler can't find it. How can I compile this?

I tried to give such command: `gcc -LC:\Users\apple\Desktop -lcs50 mario.c`

But the result is this:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcs50
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Or:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\apple\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8KpeUr.o:mario.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `GetInt'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main()
{
    int num = GetInt();
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/how-do-i-install-the-cs50-library-to-my-local-os

Comment: Did you compile `cs50.c` to a library or do you have the source file? In the latter case you might be able to compile your program with `gcc mario.c cs50.c`.

Comment: Addition to @Bodo answer: you can link your library as you tried to, but it needs to be compiled as a library, and it must reside under the directory you gave in `-L`. Linker simply can't find `libcs50.a` on your desktop.

Comment: Also, the `GetInt` looks wrong. Afaik it is `get_int("prompt goes here")` in current iterations of the cs50 library. Actually been that way for 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

```
gcc -LC:\Users\apple\Desktop -lcs50 mario.c
```

There are two problems here.

1. Always pass libraries after `.c` files or they won't actually do anything (unless `main` is in the library).
2. You appear to have a library called cs50.a; -lcs50 wants to find a file called `libcs50.a` or `libcs50.so`.

The easiest way around this problem is to not bother with `-L` or `-l` and just pass your library directly to `gcc` like this:

```
gcc mario.c cs50.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *cs50.c* is a single file, you do not need a library at all. You can compile it as needed to save a few steps; it will consume a couple milliseconds more, but most of the time you would not notice.

Just use

```
gcc mario.c cs50.c
```

and it will work (provided that both files are in the current folder).

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I put the *cs50.h* and *cs50.c* files in the same folder or directory as stdio.h; which you will find in the program files of the compiler you're using.

It worked for me.