# Can’t I use the CS50 C library on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, include, cs50

I think I found the problem -

When I use the [CS50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CS50)-files from the following source, it is not working: *[libcs50](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/develop/src)*

But when I use it from here, the compilation is possible without errors:
https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/releases

Now I have other problems, because the compiled EXE file took more than two minutes to start, but I will put this in another question so it’s clearer.

I changed the code to, and updated, the newest cs50.c and cs50.h. Files:

```c
#include "cs50.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What is your name?\n");
    printf("hello, %s\n", name);
}
```

Then I did the command again:

```
gcc string.c cs50.c
```

Now I get this huge error message:

```
</span> MSVC</span></td>
                                                                       ^
cs50.c:2959:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC458" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">pragma</span> section(&quot;.CRT$XCU&quot;,read)</td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:2959:123: error: expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
         <td id="LC458" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">pragma</span> section(&quot;.CRT$XCU&quot;,read)</td>

                                           ^
cs50.c:2959:137: error: expected identifier or '(' before ',' token
         <td id="LC458" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">pragma</span> section(&quot;.CRT$XCU&quot;,read)</td>

                                                         ^
cs50.c:2963:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC459" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER_</span>(<span class
="pl-v">FUNC,PREFIX</span>) \</td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:2963:188: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC459" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER_</span>(<span class
="pl-v">FUNC,PREFIX</span>) \</td>


                            ^
cs50.c:2967:208: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC460" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-k">static</span> <span class="pl-k">void</span> <span class="pl-e
n">FUNC</span>(<span class="pl-k">void</span>); \</td>


                                                ^
cs50.c:2967:209: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC460" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-k">static</span> <span class="pl-k">void</span> <span class="pl-e
n">FUNC</span>(<span class="pl-k">void</span>); \</td>


                                                 ^
cs50.c:2971:172: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC461" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__declspec</span>(allocate(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl
-pds">&quot;</span>.CRT$XCU<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)) void (*FU
NC##_)(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) = FUNC; \</td>


            ^
cs50.c:2971:214: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC461" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__declspec</span>(allocate(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl
-pds">&quot;</span>.CRT$XCU<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)) void (*FU
NC##_)(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) = FUNC; \</td>


                                                      ^
cs50.c:2971:242: error: stray '##' in program
         <td id="LC461" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__declspec</span>(allocate(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl
-pds">&quot;</span>.CRT$XCU<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)) void (*FU
NC##_)(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) = FUNC; \</td>



  ^~
cs50.c:2971:287: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC461" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__declspec</span>(allocate(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl
-pds">&quot;</span>.CRT$XCU<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)) void (*FU
NC##_)(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) = FUNC; \</td>



                                               ^
cs50.c:2971:288: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC461" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__declspec</span>(allocate(<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl
-pds">&quot;</span>.CRT$XCU<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)) void (*FU
NC##_)(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) = FUNC; \</td>



                                                ^
cs50.c:2975:176: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>


                ^
cs50.c:2975:219: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>


                                                           ^
cs50.c:2975:241: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>



 ^
cs50.c:2975:293: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>



                                                     ^
cs50.c:2975:328: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>




        ^
cs50.c:2975:345: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC462" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-en">__pragma</span>(comment(linker,<span class="pl-s"><span class
="pl-pds">&quot;</span>/include:<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span> PREFIX
 #FUNC <span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span></span>)) \</td>




                         ^
cs50.c:2983:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC464" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #ifde
f _WIN64</td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:2987:79: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC465" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>
                                                                               ^

cs50.c:2987:248: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC465" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>



        ^
cs50.c:2987:282: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC465" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span><span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>



                                          ^
cs50.c:2991:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC466" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">else</span></td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:2995:79: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC467" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>
                                                                               ^

cs50.c:2995:248: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC467" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>



        ^
cs50.c:2995:283: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC467" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        #
<span class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span cl
ass="pl-v">FUNC</span>) INITIALIZER_(FUNC,<span class="pl-s"><span class="pl-pds
">&quot;</span>_<span class="pl-pds">&quot;</span></span>)</td>



                                           ^
cs50.c:2999:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC468" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">endif</span></td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:3003:71: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC469" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span cl
ass="pl-k">elif</span> defined (__GNUC__) <span class="pl-c"><span class="pl-c">
//</span> GCC, Clang, MinGW</span></td>
                                                                       ^
cs50.c:3007:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC470" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span class=
"pl-v">FUNC</span>) \</td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:3007:180: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC470" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">define</span> <span class="pl-en">INITIALIZER</span>(<span class=
"pl-v">FUNC</span>) \</td>


                    ^
cs50.c:3011:237: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC471" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-k">static</span> <span class="pl-k">void</span> <span class="pl-e
n">FUNC</span>(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) __attribute__((constructor)); \</
td>


                                                                             ^
cs50.c:3011:238: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC471" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">        <
span class="pl-k">static</span> <span class="pl-k">void</span> <span class="pl-e
n">FUNC</span>(<span class="pl-k">void</span>) __attribute__((constructor)); \</
td>


                                                                              ^
cs50.c:3019:71: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC473" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span cl
ass="pl-k">else</span></td>
                                                                       ^
cs50.c:3023:75: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC474" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">error</span> The CS50 library requires some compiler-specific fea
tures, \</td>
                                                                           ^
cs50.c:3023:167: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC474" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">    #<spa
n class="pl-k">error</span> The CS50 library requires some compiler-specific fea
tures, \</td>


       ^
cs50.c:3027:179: error: stray '\' in program
         <td id="LC475" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">
  but we <span class="pl-k">do</span> not recognize this compiler/version. Pleas
e file an issue at \</td>


                   ^
cs50.c:3035:71: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC477" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#endif</t
d>
                                                                       ^
cs50.c:3076:72: error: expected identifier or '(' before '<' token
         <td id="LC487" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">}</td>
                                                                        ^
cs50.c:3089:71: error: stray '#' in program
         <td id="LC490" class="blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line">#<span cl
ass="pl-k">pragma</span> GCC diagnostic pop</td>
                                                                       ^
cs50.c:3124:12: warning: missing terminating ' character
       <!-- '"` --><!-- </textarea></xmp> --></option></form><form class="js-jum
p-to-line-form Box-body d-flex" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><i
nput name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
            ^
cs50.c:3124:12: error: missing terminating ' character
       <!-- '"` --><!-- </textarea></xmp> --></option></form><form class="js-jum
p-to-line-form Box-body d-flex" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><i
nput name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cs50.c:3145:39: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
       <li class="mr-3 mr-lg-0">&copy; 2019 GitHub, Inc.</li>
                                       ^~~~
cs50.c:3178:12: error: stray '\342' in program
     You canÔ perform that action at this time.
            ^
cs50.c:3178:13: error: stray '\200' in program
     You canÔm perform that action at this time.
             ^
cs50.c:3178:14: error: stray '\231' in program
     You canÔ01;31mmt perform that action at this time.
              ^
```

***Initial question:***

I am running into the same problem now as described in an earlier question, but the solutions described still do not work in my case:
*[How to link the CS50 C library in GCC on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432721/how-to-link-the-cs50-c-library-in-gcc-on-windows)*

This is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = <get_string("What is your name?\n");
    printf("hello, %s\n" , name);
}
```

So I try to compile the program like this:

```
gcc string.c cs50.c
```

And this is the error I get:

```
string.c:1:10: fatal error: cs50.h: No such file or directory
#include <cs50.h>
```

I tried this also with "" instead of <> at the include statements:

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string("What is your name?\n");
    printf("hello, %s\n" , name);
}
```

Then I get this error message:

```
string.c: In function 'main':
string.c:6:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'get_string'; did you m
ean 'GetString'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     string name = get_string("What is your name?\n");
                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                   GetString
string.c:6:19: warning: initialization of 'string' {aka 'char *'} from 'int' mak
es pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\P
olzi\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwLxByO.o:string.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to
 `get_string'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `cs50.h` should be in double quotes because it is local instead of in the sytem include path.  `stdio.h` should be in angles.

Comment: In the second try, using the library probably worked. However, there is no function `get_string`, which is what the error message is about.

Comment: Are you using the [latest version](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/tree/develop/src)? `GetString` was retired c. 2015 and replaced with `get_string`.

Comment: can you please share the commands?

Comment: Changed the double quotes and the angles according to the comment
Updatet the cs50-Files to the actual version according to the link in comments
But now i get a huge other error message which i updated in the thread

Comment: Did you, by chance, copy-paste the code from a web page?  You have HTML in your source code.  What editor are you using?

Comment: Take a look at the new `cs50.c` file around line 2959.  You'll find it contains something other than C code at that point.  It suggests you didn't download the file correctly (or, an outside possibility, the CS50 team accidentally published bogus code, but that is pretty unlikely).

Comment: See UPDATE2 in the inital thread - think i found the solution for the problem - but run in another problem... :=)

Comment: Here's a link that will help you: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/7291/how-do-i-install-the-cs50-library-to-my-local-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this documentation. It seems like maybe you haven't installed the <cs50.h> library in your local machine or your VS Code hasn't recognised the library for some reason.

*[CS50 Library for C](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/)*